# I can't use Roles without failing. "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred"

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, web-config, authorization

Hi I'm trying to use and understand Roles for the first time.
How can I resolve this? Do I need to add something to the `WebConfig`?

```
private static void CreateRoleIfNotExists(string role)
{
    if (!Roles.RoleExists(role)) // this line throws the error.
    {
        Roles.CreateRole(role);
    }  
}
```

Update, complete stacktrace inserted below:

`[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4856727
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, SqlConnection owningObject) +4867325
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject) +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart) +374
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +225
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +189
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +4868451
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +31
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +431
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +499
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +65
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +117
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +122
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder.Open(HttpContext context, Boolean revertImpersonate) +87
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation) +221
   System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider.RoleExists(String roleName) +478
   System.Web.Security.Roles.RoleExists(String roleName) +73
   dk.certifikat.Global.CreateRoleIfNotExists(String role)`

Comment: Your database is down, or blocked by a firewall.

Comment: @dbaseman I don't use any database before I've logged in. Do I miss a data source (to a database i'm not using)?

Comment: Check your Web.Config, the configuration of the membership provider datasource

Comment: @Massanu I don't have any. How should it look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the standard .net membership providers and roleproviders you need to setup the aspnetdb

this can be done by a command from the commandprompt

> aspnet_regsql

this can be found in you .net framework directory.
If you did this. You need to provide the application with an connectionstring to the database where the aspnetdb is running.

more about this can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649314.aspx).

Comment: Thanks I think I see what you mean. I'm wondering if I'm walking down the wrong path and doing it all wrong. I will re-think it over.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this error. I was following the example at http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/introduction-and-overview in which they also use Roles.RoleExists at some moment. When I ran the application locally with Visual Studio Express, everything worked fine. But when I tried to access the application via the web, I got the same connection error.

Turned out I had to change the web.config file.
I changed the DefaultProfileProvider, DefaultMembershipProvider and DefaultRoleProvider. I changed the connectionStringName attribute to the one I had added to the connectionStrings, namely:

```
<add name="WingtipToys" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=wingtiptoys;Integrated Security=False;User Id=wingtiptoys;Password=wingtiptoys;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|wingtiptoys.mdf;Persist Security Info=False" />
```

For example, the DefaultMembershipProvider now looks like:

```
<add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="WingtipToys" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
```

with *connectionStringName="WingtipToys"* instead of *connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"*

And then everything worked fine. This may not be the best solution, but I hope this answer can help somebody.